# Something wrong with @INC in perl?

Tags: perl

Let's imagine we are new to perl and wrote some great module `MyModule.pm`. We also wrote some great script `myscript.pl`, that need to use this module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyModule;
etc...
```

Now we will create dir `/home/user/GreatScript` and put our files in it. And trying to run `myscript.pl`...

```
cd /home/user/GreatScript
perl myscript.pl
```

Great! Now moving to another dir...

```
cd /
perl /home/user/GreatScript/myscript.pl
```

Getting some not very usefull error about `@INC` and list of paths. What is this? Now after some googling we know that `@INC` contains paths where to search our modules, and this error means that Perl can't find out MyModule.pm.

Now we can:

- Add path to system PERL5LIB var, it will add our path to the beginning of `@INC`
  Install our module to one of dirs from `@INC`
- Manually add our path to `@INC` in the `BEGIN` section
  Add `use lib '/home/user/GreatScript';` to our script, but it looks bad. What if we will move our script to other dir?
- Or use `FindBin` module to find our current dir, and use this path in `use lib "$FindBin::Bin";`, but it's not 100% effective, for example some bugs with mod_perl or [issues](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html#KNOWN-ISSUES)...
- Or use __FILE__ (or $0) variable and extract path from it using `abs_path` method from `Cwd` module. Looks like a yet another bicycle?
- Or some forgotten or missing ( Did I miss something? )

**Why this obvious and regular operation need a lot of work?** If I have one script, it's easy... But why I need to write this few additional lines of code to all my scripts? And it will not work 100%! Why perl not adding current script dir to `@INC` by default, like it does with "."?

PS: I was searching for answer to my question but find only list of solutions from the list above and some others. I hope this question is duplicate...

Comment: What do you mean "needs a lot of work"? You've already found four ways to do it. You have the same problem in essentially all languages (python, Java, ruby, anything that needs specific DLLs/SO files, ...). Heck, you even need that sort of thing to locate the perl executable itself (`PATH` settings).

Comment: All this ways have some issues and not 100% save, I thought it's not so hard to add path to current script directory on core level of perl...

Comment: what do you do when that's not what you want? What if you actually need stuff in the current path to override stuff in the script's location? Then you need something else to disable the default. Having to set something like a PATH to "modules" you use is extremely common in all languages and platforms (either directly or through some form of registry).

Comment: You are missing [`sitecustomize.pl`](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2007/10/msg129926.html) as a system-level hook (which could be used to implement user- or script-specific hooks) that can manipulate `@INC`.  That and any of the techniques you mention are better than relying on an accident of the script's cwd.  [Neil Slater's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19724377/132382) is better still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or some forgotten or missing ( Did I miss something? )

Another option: *Don't keep your module with your script*. The module is separate because it is re-usable, so put it in a library folder. This can be anything from a local library for personal projects, included with `use lib` (and perhaps referencing an environment variable you have set up for the project), to making the module into a CPAN library, and letting `cpan` manage where it goes. What you decide to do depends on how re-usable your code is, beyond how the script uses it.

> Why this obvious and regular operation need a lot of work?

It is not a lot of work in the scheme of things. Your expectation that files grouped together in the file system, should automatically be used by Perl at the language level to resolve `require` or `use` statements is not true. It's not that it is impossible, or that your expectation is unreasonable, just that Perl is not implemented that way. Changing it after the fact could affect how many existing projects work, and may be contentious - so is unlikely to change.

Comment: But even so, a command-line flag (`-R` for "relative" is currently unused) could be used to make any relative paths in `@INC` be interpreted as relative to the script instead of relative to the current working directory. This option could even be given on a shebang line, and ought not have any negative backwards-compatibility consequences.

Comment: @tobyink: It could, but whether or not it would be considered seriously as a new feature for `perl` I cannot say. The status quo is not impossible - you *can* have your preferred grouping of module files. To get a command-line flag allocated to your preference for a project structure (which would save you a line or two of code), it would need to be a deemed popular enough in the Perl community, and the concept supported by the Perl developers.

Answer (score 4):

If your use case is: "I want to have a script which accesses additional modules or other resources in the same or relative directory, and I don't want to install everything", then FindBin is a perfect solution. The limitation mentioned in the manpage happens only in persistent environments like mod_perl, but here I would propose different solutions (e.g. using FindBin only within httpd.conf, not in the scripts/modules).

(/me is a heavy FindBin user, and I am also the author of half of the KNOWN ISSUES section of the FindBin manpage)

Answer (score 2):

That is need in order to know which module would you like to use. When you move to another catalog as you said perl looks in '.' catalog so if run:

```
cd /
perl /home/user/GreatScript/myscript.pl
```

and if MyModule.pm in '/' perl will find it and will be use in `myscrpit.pl`. Now as Perl finds module in the @INC in order which catologs in it you have to keep an eye on @INC.

Summary: obvious and regular operation is need to prevent using wrong module with the same name what you want to use.